# Problems with sanskrit hyphenation in babel

Tags: luatex, fontspec, babel, hyphenation

I need to type a multilingual document, this document has both greek and sanskrit texts. But, I do not know why, the sanskrit hyphenation does not work. 
Here my MWE:

```
% !TEX engine = lualatex
% !TEX enableSynctex = yes
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{GFS Didot}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Script=Devanagari]{Siddhanta}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=sa-Deva,hyphenrules=sa-Deva]{sanskrit-devanagari}
\babelprovide[import=el]{el}


\begin{document}
{\sanskritfont\selectlanguage{sanskrit-devanagari}
  एवमनुश्रूयते--पुरा किल भगवान्स्वलोकमधितिष्ठन्परमेष्ठी विकासिनि पझविष्ठरे समुपविष्टः सुनासीरप्रमुखैर्गीर्वाणैः परिवृतो ब्रह्नोद्याः कथाः कुर्वन्नन्याश्च निरवद्या विद्यागोष्ठीर्भावयन्कदाचिदासाञ्चक्रे । तथासीनं च तं त्रिभुवनप्रतीक्ष्यं मनुदक्षचाक्षुषप्रभृतयः प्रजापतयः सर्वे च सप्तर्षिपुरःसरा महर्षयः सिषेविरे । केचिदृचः स्तुतिचतुराः समुदचारयन् । केचिदपचितिभाञ्जि यजूंष्यपछन् । केचित्प्रशंसासामानि सामानि जगुः । अपरे विवृतक्रतुक्रियातन्त्रान्मन्त्रान्व्याचचक्षिरे । विद्याविसंवादकृताश्च तत्र तेषामन्योन्यस्य विवादाः प्रादुरभवन् ।
}

{\greekfont\selectlanguage{el}
ἔννοιά ποθ᾽ ἡμῖν ἐγένετο ὅσαι δημοκρατίαι κατελύθησαν ὑπὸ τῶν ἄλλως πως βουλομένων πολιτεύεσθαι μᾶλλον ἢ ἐν δημοκρατίᾳ, ὅσαι τ᾽ αὖ μοναρχίαι, ὅσαι τε ὀλιγαρχίαι ἀνῄρηνται ἤδη ὑπὸ δήμων, καὶ ὅσοι τυραννεῖν ἐπιχειρήσαντες οἱ μὲν αὐτῶν καὶ ταχὺ πάμπαν κατελύθησαν, οἱ δὲ κἂν ὁποσονοῦν χρόνον ἄρχοντες διαγένωνται, θαυμάζονται ὡς σοφοί τε καὶ εὐτυχεῖς ἄνδρες γεγενημένοι. πολλοὺς δ᾽ ἐδοκοῦμεν καταμεμαθηκέναι καὶ ἐν ἰδίοις οἴκοις τοὺς μὲν ἔχοντας καὶ πλείονας οἰκέτας, τοὺς δὲ καὶ πάνυ ὀλίγους, καὶ ὅμως οὐδὲ τοῖς ὀλίγοις τούτοις πάνυ τι δυναμένους χρῆσθαι πειθομένοις τοὺς δεσπότας.
}
\end{document}
```

Here the output:
[image]

Why greek hyphenation works and sanskrit does not work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the patterns for Sanskrit are named `sanskrit`. Here is your example with some changes and notes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{babel}

\babelprovide[
    import=sa-Deva,
    hyphenrules=sanskrit,
        % I'm not sure if the hyphens must be shown. If not, just
        % uncomment the following line:
    % typography/prehyphenchar = 0
  ]{sanskrit-devanagari}
\babelprovide[import=el-polyton]{el}

% Let babel select the fonts. I'm using a 'generic' font for Devanagari.

\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[el]{rm}{GFS Didot}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{sanskrit-devanagari}

एवमनुश्रूयते--पुरा किल भगवान्स्वलोकमधितिष्ठन्परमेष्ठी विकासिनि पझविष्ठरे समुपविष्टः सुनासीरप्रमुखैर्गीर्वाणैः परिवृतो ब्रह्नोद्याः कथाः कुर्वन्नन्याश्च निरवद्या विद्यागोष्ठीर्भावयन्कदाचिदासाञ्चक्रे । तथासीनं च तं त्रिभुवनप्रतीक्ष्यं मनुदक्षचाक्षुषप्रभृतयः प्रजापतयः सर्वे च सप्तर्षिपुरःसरा महर्षयः सिषेविरे । केचिदृचः स्तुतिचतुराः समुदचारयन् । केचिदपचितिभाञ्जि यजूंष्यपछन् । केचित्प्रशंसासामानि सामानि जगुः । अपरे विवृतक्रतुक्रियातन्त्रान्मन्त्रान्व्याचचक्षिरे । विद्याविसंवादकृताश्च तत्र तेषामन्योन्यस्य विवादाः प्रादुरभवन् ।

\selectlanguage{el}

ἔννοιά ποθ᾽ ἡμῖν ἐγένετο ὅσαι δημοκρατίαι κατελύθησαν ὑπὸ τῶν ἄλλως πως βουλομένων πολιτεύεσθαι μᾶλλον ἢ ἐν δημοκρατίᾳ, ὅσαι τ᾽ αὖ μοναρχίαι, ὅσαι τε ὀλιγαρχίαι ἀνῄρηνται ἤδη ὑπὸ δήμων, καὶ ὅσοι τυραννεῖν ἐπιχειρήσαντες οἱ μὲν αὐτῶν καὶ ταχὺ πάμπαν κατελύθησαν, οἱ δὲ κἂν ὁποσονοῦν χρόνον ἄρχοντες διαγένωνται, θαυμάζονται ὡς σοφοί τε καὶ εὐτυχεῖς ἄνδρες γεγενημένοι. πολλοὺς δ᾽ ἐδοκοῦμεν καταμεμαθηκέναι καὶ ἐν ἰδίοις οἴκοις τοὺς μὲν ἔχοντας καὶ πλείονας οἰκέτας, τοὺς δὲ καὶ πάνυ ὀλίγους, καὶ ὅμως οὐδὲ τοῖς ὀλίγοις τούτοις πάνυ τι δυναμένους χρῆσθαι πειθομένοις τοὺς δεσπότας.

\end{document}
```

[image: Greek+Sanskrit Babel]

By the way, wouldn't it be better to import `el-polyton` or `grc`?

**Edit.** I've changed the original suggestion to suppress the hyphens for a better one.

Comment: I am using the `fontspec` package because I need to select some fonts features, like alternations, stylistics changes and etc. About the options `grc` and `el-polyton` , I did not find it in Babel PDF-Documentation (in CTAN.org, there I just found -ee for Ewe, -el for greek and after en-US for english), I have a `texlive` updated (with `texlive-langgreek` package installed) and I got the error: The `ini` file for `el-polyton` and `grc` was not found. Where I can find these files ? I installed the `babel-greek` package, with the `greek.ldf` file, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: (1) Font features can be set as an optional argument before the font name: `\babelfont[greek]{rm}[...]{FreeSerif}`. (2) As to the the `ini` files, they are recent (v3.36 or v3.40) and maybe there is a problem with the installer, but they belong to the `babel` core.